# Android Duplicate class error on while using nav sdk and map sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, supportmapfragment

I want to use Google map and Navigation SDK Both but getting Duplicate class error. If excludes 'com.google.android.gms' SupportMapFragment and other map classes are not found.

Following implementations are used

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.maps:navsdk:3.2.0' 
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.transportation:transportation-driver:4.0.0'
```

Following dependencies are added

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate found in modules jetified-navsdk-4.3.2-runtime (com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2) and jetified-play-services-maps-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory found in modules jetified-navsdk-4.3.2-runtime (com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2) and jetified-play-services-maps-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap found in modules jetified-navsdk-4.3.2-runtime (com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2) and jetified-play-services-maps-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$CancelableCallback found in modules jetified-navsdk-4.3.2-runtime (com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2) and jetified-play-services-maps-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$InfoWindowAdapter found in modules jetified-navsdk-4.3.2-runtime (com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2) and jetified-play-services-maps-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnCameraChangeListener found in modules

Comment: try adding ```android.enableJetifier=true``` in "gradle.properties" file

Answer (score 1):

This error usually happens when you add dependencies, which uses different versions of some classes under the hood, and build tool can't figure out which version of a class it have to use (in your case it's classes from `com.google.android.maps:navsdk:4.3.2`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0`).

To get rid of this error you should consider to upgrade some of your libraries.

Note: there is a command which will help you to debug your problem: `./gradlew app:dependencies`. It shows dependencies tree of a project, so you could faster detect dependencies which are used by your libraries.

Comment: Upgrading version is not working